# Check whether javascript lib already exist

Tags: include, liferay, javascript, conflict

Can i check whether if my javascript ext-lib such as fancybox plugin have already existed in my page(don't matter its version)?
I use liferay portlet, it can be place two same portlet in one page, I am already have some script confict now. (Liferay AUI script on layout configuration panel, slider in some assetPublisher ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are testing for native javascript functions (i.e. built–in or created using javascript), then:

```
if (typeof foo == 'function')
```

will always work, regardless of which library you are using. e.g. to test if jQuery is available:

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'function')
```

I would not trust the jQuery *isFunction* method for host objects, and if you aren't testing host objects, typeof is completely reliable.

#### Edit

Oh, I should add that if you are testing methods of host objects, there are many aspects to consider. The following is sufficient in the vast majority of cases:

```
if (hostObject && hostObject.method) {
  // call hostObject.method
}
```

It’s worth noting that host objects aren’t required to comply with ECMA-262 (though most modern implementations do to a large extent, at least for DOM objects). There are a number of implementations in use that have host objects that, when tested with `typeof` will return “unknown” or similar, some older ones even threw errors.

Some host objects throw errors if tested with `object.prototype.toString.call(hostObject)` (which jQuery's *isFunction* function uses), so unless you are going to implement a robust *isHostMethod* function, the above will do in the vast majority of cases.

Comment: Use triple equals for JavaScript

Comment: Not always — use strict equality where required, otherwise use abstract. Typeof always returns a string, in the above `==` and `===` will produce exactly the same result in every case. `==` is less to type and others aren't thinking "Why is strict used here?". Some recommend strict as the algorithm is shorter and (therefore) may be faster, but the difference in speed is infinitesimally small and may favour abstract depending on the implementation. I favour readability.

Comment: Well, +1 for defending the use of `==`, even though I've been switching to `===` for JSLint/Hint validation and as you're comparing 2 strings there shouldn't be any difference in the result.

Comment: From the [documentation](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html): `JSLint cannot reliably determine if == is being used correctly, so it is best to not use == and != `. So it could be said that the recommendation of `===` is due to JSLint's shortcomings, not because it's necessarily more appropriate for a particular situation.

Answer (score 1):

To check if a generic JS lib is loaded (aka not a jQuery plugin) test one of its functions:

```
if ($.isFunction(pluginFunction)) {
    // Code to run if generic library is loaded
}
```

To check if a jQuery plugin is loaded:

```
if (jQuery().pluginName) {
    // Code to run if plugin is loaded
}
```

Hope this helps!